# Azure IOT hub instantaneously disconnect when having a network change or a network disconnection

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am using IOT hub c# sdk netframework 4.8.

It seems that a network change instantaneously disconnect the iot hub connection, as well when disconnecting the network I am also getting connection state change for the iot session.

This is not inline with my parameters:

"AmqpMaxPoolSize": 2048,
"AmqpConnectionIdleTimeout": 960,
"IoTOpenTimeoutInSeconds": 900,
"IoTOperationTimeoutInSeconds": 600,
"IoTSendingRetryTimes": 5,

If you have more information or idea about why Iot hub session in disconnecting instantaneously, please let me know.

Thanks,
Hak

Comment: `as well when disconnecting the network I am also getting connection state change for the iot session.` What were you expecting instead?

Comment: I was expecting a management such as signalR with reconnection try behind the scene.

Comment: Did it _not_ try to reconnect behind the scenes?

Comment: seems not, the disconnection is instantaneous

Comment: The disconnection might be instantaneous - but does it try to reconnect straight after that?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. You can register your event handler for connection status change in your  DeviceClient instance if you want to have any logic.

```
client.SetConnectionStatusChangesHandler((status, reason) => {
    if (status != ConnectionStatus.Connected 
         && reason == ConnectionStatusChangeReason.No_Network)
    {
        // do stuffs
    }
});
```

When you say

> This is not inline with my parameters:
>
> "AmqpMaxPoolSize": 2048, "AmqpConnectionIdleTimeout": 960,
> "IoTOpenTimeoutInSeconds": 900, "IoTOperationTimeoutInSeconds": 600,
> "IoTSendingRetryTimes": 5

none of those has much to do with disconnection.

Also there are some inbuilt retry mechanism in IoTHub SDK iteself. Refer [Manage connectivity and reliable messaging by using Azure IoT Hub device SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-reliability-features-in-sdks).